# HTML/CSS - Remove/Hide a layer header

Tags: html, css

I have a page here: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/why-iliveaccountable/

And i need hide the part:

[image]

I used the chrome inspect element and tried to remove this code:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display:none;
}
```

But still it did not work.

Any idea what should I do to hide that part and just retain the menu above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspect the element you will get this class, add `display:none` to it

```
.header-v4 .logo {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Great! wohoo! sdafdsfsdfds

Comment: U r Welcome @Mikk tick the answer if it is correct , it will be useful to others Mikk.